# why chart.js doesn't show result in Bootstrap block

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bootstrap-5

The chart.html does not show the bar chart, which is supposed to be the one in https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/

In `chart.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block js %}
    <div>
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="../static/js/try.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

In `try.js`

```
import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js';
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please check if import of chart.js is successful (in developer console of browser for example - press F12). Also that something else is not blocking running js.

Answer (score 0):

The `import` failed in `try.js`.

The solution is to relocate the `import` in `chart.html`.

In `chart.html` :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block js %}
    <div>
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/try.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried this, which worked.